# How can I toggle any form input (not all at once)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to toggle input display in a form, not every input. I assigned a button for every input element, so when that button is clicked, that input should appear or disappear.

I was searching to solve this problem, but any function I found is for the entire form, I was trying js, jquery, but it won't work.

Input is something like:

```
 <input type="text"  id='id1' placeholder="Insert here">
```

And the button:

```
 <button id="b_id1" onclick="myFunction(id1)">Click Me id1</button>
```

I was using JSfunction, but it won't help:

```
function myFunction(id) {
  var x = document.getElementById('id');
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

I got this error too:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
>       at myFunction

Comment: Where is the function `myFunction` getting called?

Comment: I just edited, sorry

Comment: Your "id" parameter in function call should be wrapped within quotes(')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extending @MauriceNino 's comment, if you want generic code, you can use the following. You can assign a common `onclick` function to the buttons which pass the button object upon clicking. From that, you can extract the input box id and manipulate that.

```js
function myFunction(id) {
var id = id.id.split("_")[1];//extract input id from button id
  var x = document.getElementById(id);
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text"  id='id1' placeholder="Insert here">

 <button id="b_id1" onclick = "myFunction(this)">Click Me id1</button>
```

Comment: What the [1] does after split function?

Comment: @DonPaul `.split` will return an array in which we need the element present in the first index. So we use [1] which selects `id1` which is the id of the button

Answer (score 1):

So, you're using a function when a button is pressed but I don't see any "onclick" in your button.

```
<button onclick="myFunction('b_id1')" id="b_id1">Click Me id1</button>
```

Add this action to your button and the function should work.
The error displayed is due to the fact that you're passing a NULL id in your function so the style of the display just doesn't exist.

Comment: I copied the wrong button. But the id exists, why is not working?

Answer (score 1):

You need add `'` to javascript to detect id1 is string:

```
<button id="b_id1" onclick="myFunction('id1')">Click Me id1</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use jQuery, try this code

```
function myFunction(id) {
  if($(id).css('display') === "none") {
    $(id).show();
  } else {
    $(id).hide();
  }
}
```

with your button

```
<button id="b_id1" onclick="myFunction('#id1');">Click Me id1</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myFunction(e) {
   var x = document.getElementById('id1');
   x.classList.toggle("mystyle");
}
```

```css
.mystyle{
  display:none;
 }
```

```html
<input type="text"  id='id1' placeholder="Insert here">
  <button id="b_id1" onclick="myFunction()">Click Me id1</button>
```

Comment: You have parameter e in function title, but when you call it there is none. And if I have a subordinate css class, I need to put both? Like .mystyle.mystyle2{...}

Comment: Why you want to subordinate css class in that?, it is custom class added to input element when 1st click and removed on 2nd (toggle).

Comment: If you want to add 2 class you can use like this "x.classList.add('mystyle','mystyle1')"

Answer (score 0):

It is the issue with your ID. as you can on javascript line 2

```
var x = document.getElementById('id');
```

You have delcare an wrong ID. It should be called `"id1"`

Correct is : `var x = document.getElementById('id1');`

```
function myFunction(id) {
  var x = document.getElementById('id1');
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Code Standards:

Firstly, you have to understand the differences between variables and constants.
As you write 
`<button id="b_id1" onclick="myFunction(id1)">Click Me id1</button>`
 **id1** is treated like a variable, which in this case has never been declared. This lead to a reference to undefined, also **id1=** *undefined*.
As you call myFunction() you are passing as argument undefined, also like **myFunction(*undefined*);** try writing instead

`<button id="b_id1" onclick="myFunction('id1')">Click Me id1</button>`

The same issue but with the inverse solutions appears when you declare the function

```
function myFunction(id) {
  var x = document.getElementById('id');
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

on line 2, in `var x = document.getElementById('id');` you are referencing to the string **'id'** which is a constant and not the variable passed in the parameters **id**. Same as before try rewriting your function like this:

```
function myFunction(id) {
  var x = document.getElementById(id);
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

#### Clean coding:

I'd also recommend you to work with classes and not direct with styles, in order to make the code easier to read and to refactor, in case you want to implement some new feature. For this solution I'd use the `setAttribute()` function, which is well explained here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp